# Tabular in footnote, position of the footnote number

Tags: tables, footnotes

If I create a tabular within a footnote, the position of the footnote number is not at the first line of the footnote, but in its middle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Some text.\footnote{Some text inside a footnote. Longer than one line. The footnote number is in the first line.}

Some more text.\footnote{%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
First column                     & Second column \\
Second row                       & Something. \\
Third row                        & Now here roughly we have the footnote number \\
Fourth row                       & Something more. \\
Fifth row                        & Something more. \\
Sixth row                        & Something more. \\
Seventh row                      & Something more. 
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: image of footnotes]

Which is not what I would have expected. How would one shift the number to the top?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just provide the top alignment option `[t]` in your `tabular` environment will solve the issue, i.e.,

`\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}`